# How do I play a MIDI file into a MIDI channel?

Tags: software, midi, synthesizer

So I've got a MIDI file of some melody I composed, and a software synthesizer I want to play it through, called ZynAddSubFX running on Debian Linux. The problem is, it only accepts inputs through MIDI channels, which I understand to be what a MIDI keyboard plugged into my computer would send signals to. Is there a way I can play a MIDI file directly into one of these channels with a clever bit of software or some weird computer witchcraft so that my softsynth will pick it up and be able to play it on my preferred synth sound?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! You may be able to load the MIDI file straight into your project without playing it in through the MIDI input, however I've never used ZynAddSubFX  before so that's just a guess. If you haven't already, please take the [tour](https://music.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help centre](https://music.stackexchange.com/help) for more information about this site!

Comment: How did you create the MIDI file? Whatever program you used for that should be able to play it back. Anyway, does the softsynth show up in the output of `aplaymidi -l`?

Answer (score 2):

This should be easy, If you're running JACK, which I assume you are. All you need is a sequencer that can import MIDI files. I took a quick look at the Rosegarden docs and yes it can import MIDI files. Just connect the MIDI out from Rose or what ever is your sequencer of choice to the Zyn input. And then of course press play from Rose. All should be well. And of course you pipe the audio output from Zyn into a recorder if you want to.